# Create a Menu Item That Links to My Web App on Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Im new to Google Apps Development and I am trying out the Google Apps Script. I created a simple Web App with a UI that when I clicked on the button, it will list all the files I have under "Test Folder" folder. The Web App works well when I published and deploy as web app. You can try this link https://script.google.com/a/macros/siteforged.com/s/AKfycbyt2QSo_lsIQqay_FvOv3PI8CgibJ4P5MEW4R-I1aI/dev to see.

However, I am really curious on how I can create a menu item on the "More" drop down menu in Google Drive, that when I clicked on that Menu, it will bring me to that app.

Can someone point me to the documentation on how I will do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, only you can see scripts that are published from "Test your latest code" (ones that end in /dev).

The only way (from what I know) that you can change how a user experiences http://drive.google.com is by implementing [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/?hl=en). Apps Scripts are unable to do this.

Comment: Is that the only way to do that? What if I register it in web store? So does that mean that the purpose of http://script.google.com is just to test the script that you are going to use once you develop a web app using the sdk? Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: [You can take a look at this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_chrome_web_store), but it seems that an app in the webstore is just a web app. Meaning that it's simply a website (more or less) that you can navigate to and display a user interface.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really confused and overwhelmed with their documentation. What I don't understand is how I(and the other users under my domain) can use the app that I created using Google's script editor(http://script.google.com) without registering it to Web Store. What I want to happen is like for example I created an app for Gmail to send emails to multiple users in just one click, I created that app using script editor, I would like to have a way to install it on the Gmail of all the users under my domain. I'm really confused of how I will do that.

Comment: The best way to make a script available to all the users of your domain is to create a Site (or use an existing Site) and create an apps script gadget within that site.